# PHP How to send data to another page with header(redirect)

Tags: php, request, session-variables

In my website the index will redirect to a controller that will access the DAO and needs set the data in a variable to show in the view. How do i set this datas? Is the $_SESSION the best way to do that?

I try the $_REQUEST, making this:

(Index.php)

```
<?php
$_REQUEST['test'] = "TEST!!!!";
$redirect = "controllers/controllerIndex.php";
header("location:$redirect");
```

(controllerIndex.php)

```
<?php
echo $_REQUEST['test'];
```

But i received the error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: test in C:\xampp\htdocs\PlataformaPHP\controllers\controllerIndex.php on line 2
```

Comment: you need sessions for that and not `$_REQUEST`

Comment: You can use $_SESSION for that, just make sure you start a session

Comment: Like Fred suggested, use a session. Or if you don't want to spill cookies (heheh) add a querystring and use `$_GET`

Comment: Depending on the data you are sending you either need to use sessions or you can just append the data to the URL... e.g. `$redirect = "controllers/controllerIndex.php?test=TEST!!!!` and then use `$_GET['test']`.

You are probably better off with sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question, $_SESSION would be better.

You can also unset all your $_SESSION variables as described here
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php

Comment: search and replace `$_session` and `$_sessionn` => `$_SESSION` - That **must** be in uppercase. Otherwise, that would throw an undefined `$_` variable notice.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned already, [PHP SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) variables are the solution you're looking for. It is important that you include `session_start();` at the top of each PHP page that requires access to the session variable. Take a look at this which should help with your problem:

Index.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['test'] = "TEST!!!!";
    $redirect = "controllers/controllerIndex.php";
    header("location:$redirect");
    exit();
?>
```

Controller.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['test'];
    ...
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `$_SESSION` is probably the best solution, but the other option would be to just add the parameters to your `header()` url and they will be passed in the $_GET array.

```
$redirect = "controllers/controllerIndex/test";
header("location:$redirect");
```

Or without the Framework idea

```
header("Location: xxx.php?test");
```